# Render partial MissingTemplate in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

[Update]Sorry, for the stupid typo

The render methods works fine in my application .
but this time when I add 
`= render 'trail_count'` in index 
and show me ActionView::MissingTemplate in Orders#index
I have no ideas at all. Do I Miss something?

```
= render 'blocks'
%hr
= render 'disqus'
= render 'trail_count'


[orders] $ ls _*
_blocks.html.haml*      _fb_like_box.html.erb*  _trial_count.html.haml*
_disqus.html.erb*       _form.html.haml*
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `"trail_count" !=  "trial_count"`

`= render 'trial_count'` should work